# DNA like marine animal or egg

Tags: ichthyology, marine-biology, eggs

[image]What is the name of the marine egg or living being that is transparent like a jelly fish or a Venus girdle, with a shape like a DNA or better like a chain of infinites, long as half of a hand and large as half of a hand nail?

- Imagine a DNA-like strand but with no internal "sticks", white-ish, 10 cm long and 2 cm wide

Alternatively, how do I narrow my research in order to find the name of what I saw underwater?

The image seems too simplified but I just saw something like that, pretty simple, essential and little.

Comment: Is there a way to upload an image here? I used a paste bin but in case I can upload it. ( link to pastebin: https://pasteboard.co/Iv4fT7W.png )

Comment: @AMDP You can [edit] your post and copy the image into the question editor or use the image uploader. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)